# How is the magic command timeit and time different in python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Am wondering why the magic command `%%timeit` does keeps on running even after the end of the loop

```
from time import sleep

def timer(limit):  
    for ran in range(0, limit):
        print(ran)
        sleep(1)

# First cell with magic command %time 
%%time
timer(10)  # Stops when ran = 9 as expected

# Second cell with magic command %timeit
%%timeit
timer(10) # Goes on infinitely
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not run infinitely, it just does multiple loops to be able to predict a mean runtime and its std deviation. When I tried on my jupyter notebook, it stopped after calling timer 7 times.

Note also that you should only use one "%" and write the command in the same line as the magic function

Comment: Noted! I missed that. Does the %% has an effect in the execution?

Comment: I suppose you might just have a different jupyter version than me. If I copy paste your code, I get an error "Line magic function `%%time` not found.", so I can only execute your code with one "%" sign. I suppose if it works for you, it works not differently.